# First Boost program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have tried to write my first Boost program from information on the Boost libraries site.
Here is the code:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

It shows me this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: boost_librarys, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  boost_librarys.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: The kernel32 library belongs to Windows and has nothing to do with Boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link error you're getting means that your program isn't linking to the correct libraries.  Since the error refers to a Microsoft system library (`kernel.lib`), you'll need to make sure you've got your system set up correctly.  This isn't a Boost problem *per se*, although it may be Boost that's interested in linking with `kernel.lib`.

Comment: Actually, kernel32.lib is on the list of default libraries as it's used by Visual Studio's Standard Library (MSVCRT)

Comment: @MSalters:  So it's not a Boost problem _per se_ and the original poster should check that his system is set up correctly.

Comment: My statement was and is that is is _provably not_ a Boost problem. "Not _per se_ a Boost problem" keeps the possibility open that is is.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to a [similiar question outside SO](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/426d85b4-db84-4c01-a9d4-d3fd025339c0) was:

> Download and install the Windows SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en)

<sub>(link in quote may not be fitting for your system)</sub>

Comment: kernel32.lib is always installed with VS (well, maybe except for bitorrent versions, i don't know)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the Windows SDK installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are on Visual, there is NO reason why kernel32.lib wouln'd be around. Anyway, it should be in C:/Program Files(x86)/MS Visual Studio/VC/lib

My guess is that you mistyped something in the project's configuration. Every lib, every additional path should be separated by a ';'. If you're unsure, click on the right [...] , in the new window there should be one item by line only.